# How to invalidate Identiy provider's(WSO2 IS 5.0.0) session with service providers session

Tags: wso2, saml, wso2-identity-server

Environment - WSO2 IS 5.0.0, sample app

I could invalidate sample application session. but I need to destroy user session in IDP along with sample application session.

1. Is this a out of the box feature in wso2 ?
2. If not, how can I do it using IS 5.0.0 or is this supported in IS 5.1.0 ?

Comment: Do you use SP initiated sso ?

Comment: Yes. I'm using sp initiated sso.

Answer (score 0):

Please find answers for your questions.As I remember, you have to install service pack2 to send IDP initiated logout request.

1. WSO2 IS(5.0, 5.1) does not provide this facility as an out of the box with SP initiated sso.
2. You can use IDP initiated sso.The flow is explaining in the below.

i). you have to send an IDP initiated logout request to identity provider.

Request should be look like this - `https://localhost:9443/samlsso?slo=true`

ii). when IS receive a logout request, IS send logout request to other service providers those are configured with IS.

iii). Then invalidate other service providers sessions and service provider send a logout response to IDP(IS).

iv). After receive logout response from service providers, IS destroy its user session for particular user and send a logout response to service provider which requested the logout request.

v). service provider invalidate its own session.

Comment: Thank you @Madura. I have two questions. 1. how can I create idp initiated sso ? 2. Is there any document for this ?

Comment: When you are creating a service provider, you can find a check box called "enable IDP initiated sso". tick that check box.

Comment: I have enable check box. but still I'm getting an error. I will install service pack2 and let you know.